# Mysql: First Select then Update in One Query

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I need to select the rows of a table then update the field of the rows.
For example:

```
"SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `timestamp`>'1422680952'"
```

Then I want to update a field of that rows.

Comment: for exampe: "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `timestamp`>'1422680952' update set `display`='1'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you describe, returning a resultset from a `SELECT` *and* performing an `UPDATE` cannot be performed in a single SQL statement in MySQL.

You would need two separate SQL statements: a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE`.

In terms of MySQL, it is not necessary to run a `SELECT` before running an `UPDATE`, it's possible to run just an `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE `messages` SET somecol = 'somevalue' WHERE `timestamp`>'1422680952'
```

(The query in the question is enclosed in double quotes. That leads us to suspect that you are running this statement from a database interface library in a language such as PHP.)

It is possible to get multiple statements to execute as part of a single transaction. But as far as how the MySQL server itself is actually processing the specified operations, that's going to be two separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

For updating the row, you don't necessarily have to select the rows. Try something like:

```
UPDATE messages
SET display = 1
WHERE timestamp >'1422680952'
```

Answer (score 1):

**CAVEAT: This code is not presented as an answer or as a working code. But to further explain the concept of the question.**

I think what the OP wants is something like this -

`"SELECT *, (UPDATE messages SET display = display + 1 WHERE key = key) AS display FROM messages WHERE timestamp > '1422680952'"`

This is possible with `SELECT` as the sub query, but I can't say if it's possible with `UPDATE`.

I came across this question when I ran into a similar case in my application. I needed to store the number of views, i.e. number of database hits on a `table`.`row` without writing 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transaction for this purpose
where you can have both select and update inside Transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;
 
  -- Let's get the current value
  SELECT value FROM counters WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
 
   -- Increment the counter
  UPDATE counters SET value = value + 1 WHERE id = 1;
 
  COMMIT;
```

Generally it is done with this way

```
try {
    /* First of all, let's begin a transaction */
    $db->beginTransaction();

    /* A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown */
    $db->query('select query');
    $db->query('update query');

    /* If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown */
    /* i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction */
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    /* An exception has been thrown */
    /* We must rollback the transaction */
    $db->rollback();
}
```

Comment: how to use mysql transaction in php?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the syntax below, if you purpose is just updating the table:

```
Update messages
Set display = 1
Where timestamp >'1422680952'
```

Comment: ...but it's not

Comment: I'm not sure what am i missing here? Its too old of an answer to remember but i see OPs comment on question thread asking for updating `display=1`. 

Other answers including the accepted one that came after mine have the same sql from what i can see yet mine is getting downvotes -- what am i missing here lol? not that i care about the downvotes but there's something i am not seeing here :D